# Performance: int vs. byte vs. custom int

Tags: c#, performance

I'm writing a program in which I need a couple of values to always be a value ranged from 0 to 255, I want to cap them at 255 so to speak. I would like to know what my best option is, performance wise:

- int, I'd have to place numerous checks throughout the code
- byte, would throw an exception, so I would still need checks
- custom int, can be programmed to automatically trim values down or increase them to what I want, but might be lacking in performance (not sure)

Which option is best for my situation? (Other suggestions are also welcome)

Comment: "byte, would throw an exception, so I would still need checks" - what exceptions do you mean?

Comment: Benchmark and see for yourself which is faster

Comment: @astef Oh I might have it confused with something else, but I was under the impression it would throw an exception when you assign a value that is out of range?

Comment: @MikeSW I don't know how to, that's the very reason I asked it here

Comment: Use the Stopwatch class. Btw custom int vs int in 99.9999999% of cases will never be a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like this my first thought would not be about performance but about usability.  The perf impact would be hard to gauge without a good deal better understanding of your code and ultimately a profiler is going to be the true judge of the change.  Instead I would focus on making it easy to use then test the perf of that solution.

Having a custom type here doesn't seem unreasonable.  Presumably you'd want to cap every individual operation at 255 vs. capping the final outcome.  For example 255 + 100 - 50 should equal 205 not 255.  If so a custom type is your best bet and can be implemented along these lines

```
struct MyInt {
  public readonly int Value;

  public MyInt(int value) {
    Value = Math.Min(value, 255);
  }

  public static MyInt operator+(MyInt left, MyInt right) {
    return new MyInt(left.Value + right.Value); 
  }

  public static MyInt operator-(MyInt left, MyInt right) { 
    return new MyInt(left.Value - right.Value);
  }

  // etc ...
}
```

Note on such a type you should also consider implementing interfaces such as `IComparable`, `IComparable<T>` and `IEquatable<T>`

Comment: Don't forget IComparable :) and a ToInt() method

Comment: @MikeSW the int is directly accessible through `Value`.  I'll list the interfaces that the Op should consider

Comment: Can a `readonly` field be changed after the type has been constructed? see [readonly])http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes a readonly field cannot be assigned to after the type is constructed.  A class type which is readonly can change because it can change without assignment.  A struct though can't change.  Unless of course the struct containing the readonly field is assigned to.

Comment: OK , your type is immutable, like it should be! I overlooked it.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes definitely, mutable structs are evil, tricksy types :)